# Base64 Android encode to PHP decode make error

Tags: php, android, android-emulator, base64

I'm a french guy, so, I'm sorry for my english...

I'm developing an Android App which communicate with a PHP REST service. So, when I try to encode an image file into Base64 like this :

```
InputStream fileInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
int b;
while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
    out.write(b);
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
String encoded = new String(android.util.Base64.encode(out.toString()
            .getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));
```

On server side, I make :

```
$data=base64_decode(chunk_split($base64BinaryData));
```

The result is that my image file is corrupted!

INFO : the image is made by an Intent to android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Activity in Emulator mode (avd 5554)

I've already read lots of discussions about similar problem but nothing fix my bug.

thanks for help

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that:

```
out.toString().getBytes()
```

is wrong. What type is the "out"? If that's an image, then you need to get the raw bytes of the image, not the bytes of the string representation of the object.

Comment: out is the StringWriter that receive the BufferedInputStream read of the image file (I've change my native post with the full code)

Comment: You shouldn't be writing to a StringWriter, you are working with a bytestream which means that when you write to a StringWriter it will try to decode it in the default encoding, and when retrieving the bytes it will encode it using the default encoding once again but this time it will have already dropped "bytes" that it can't understand. You need to get the byte array without the StringWriter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's right! Use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of StringWriter resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just drop the chunk_split?

Also, can you hash the two binaries? Perhaps using sha1 and see if they're actually different?

Comment: In fact, the hash are exactly same! Ok, I think the substitute image from Android Emulator is not usable (just to available in Android App). I've to try my app on real device and I'll tell you the issue. Thanks for your very nice clarification.